# Yacc parse won't finish reduction of a production

Tags: c, yacc, lex

I am working on building a small interpreter through lax and yacc that works on a basic programming language that performs addition and multiplication as well as printing lists of ints.

For example the instruction:

```
Print(2,3,4);
```

Should output: 2 3 4

and the instruction:

```
Print(+(2,3));
```

should output: 5

The first print instruction works perfectly fine. However any addition instruction (+ followed by a list) works itself out and the action returns the correct answer (found out through printf) but it seems yacc stops before executing the outer print instruction occurs after the addition instruction.

Here is my .l file:

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
%}

digit [0-9]

%%
{digit}{digit}*     {yylval.str = strdup(yytext); return IntLit;}
Print               {return Print;}
\+                  {yylval.str = strdup(yytext); return '+';}
\*                  {yylval.str = strdup(yytext); return '*';}
\(                  {return '(';}
\)                  {return ')';}
\,                  {return ',';}
\;                  {return ';';}
\t                  {}
\r                  {}
\n                  {}

%%

    
int yywrap () {
    return 1;
}
```

And here is my .y file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


extern int yylex();
extern int yyparse();
extern int yyerror(char *s);
extern char *yytext;

void doPrint(char *s);
int evaluate(char *c, char *s);
char* append(char *s, char *s2);
char* makeSingle(char *s);

%}

%union {
  char character;
  char *str;
}

%type <str> Item
%type <str> IntLit
%type <str> List
%type <str> Func

%token Print
%token IntLit

%%

Prog        :   StmtSeq                 { };
StmtSeq     :   Stmt StmtSeq            { };
StmtSeq     :                           { };
Stmt        : Print '(' List ')' ';'    { doPrint($3); };   
List        : List ',' Item             { $$ = append($1, $3); };
List        : Item                      { $$ = makeSingle($1); };
Item        : Func '(' List ')'         { $$ = evaluate($1, $3); };
Item        : IntLit                    { $$ = $1;};
Func        : '+'                       {$$ = yylval.str; };
Func        : '*'                       {$$ = yylval.str; };

%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    //yydebug = 1;
    return yyparse();
}

void doPrint(char *s){
    char * token = strtok(s, ",");
    while(token != NULL){
        printf("%s", token);
        printf(" ");
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int evaluate(char *c, char *s){
    char * result;
    int res;
    int x;
    char * token;
    int cmp = strcmp(c, "+");
    if(cmp == 0){
        token = strtok(s, ",");
        res = 0;
        while(token != NULL){
            x = atoi(token);
            res = res + x;
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
        sprintf(result,"%d",res);
    } else {
        token = strtok(s, ",");
        res = 1;
        while(token != NULL){
            x = atoi(token);
            res = res * x;
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
        sprintf(result,"%d",res);
    }
    printf("resultstring is: '%s'\n", result);
    return result;
}

char* append(char *s, char *s2){
    char * result = s;
    strcat(result, ",");
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}

char* makeSingle(char *s){
    //char * result;
    //sprintf(result, "%d", c);
    //return result;
    return s;
}

extern int yyerror(char *s)  {
  printf(s);
  return 1;
}
```

If I input the instructions:

```
Print(2,3,4);
Print(+(2,3));
```

The first print instruction works as expected, but the second instruction stops before printing the result of the addition, but after the evaluation is done.

I'm new to yacc/lex and I'm not sure why yacc is stopping without printing the result of the addition. Shouldn't the result of the addition be an "Item" which can be rewritten as a "List" and then printed properly? Any help or recommendations would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**Edit**
After looking more into the output when `yydebug = 1;` I found that the parse abruptly ends (I believe) before a full reduce is done. The last section of the debug process reads:

```
Reducing stack by rule 7 (line 40):
    $1 = nterm Func ()
    $2 = token '(' ()
    $3 = nterm List ()
    $4 = token ')' ()
```

There is no `$$` in this reduction as there is in all the other reductions done before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you see when you do: `doPrint(1);` ?
You have a line in doPrint: `char * token = strtok(s, ",");`
When you go through the evaluate function you consume all of the commas, leaving a single number. When you call doPrint, there is no comma in the string so it returns NULL.
You could have a second if, for when it returns NULL (but the string has contents), or you can rework how you are parsing the string.
By the way, strdup() returns a malloced string which you don't free.
You also call strcat() using the strings received from strdup, you're writing to memory and you don't know the size. strcat() will let you overflow buffers.
A better way, when you are appending a string to another and you don't know their sizes is to do something like this:

```
char *mergestrings(char *str1,char *str2) {
  char *newstr=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+1));
  strcpy(newstr,str1);
  strcat(newstr,str2);
  free(str1);
  free(str2);
  return newstr;
}
```

or use realloc or something else, but you should pay attention to what you do with memory.

The big problems were the definition of the evaluate function and usage of pointers.
scanner.l:

```
%{
#include "../obj/y.tab.h"
%}

digit 0|(([1-9])[0-9]*)
operator [+*]

%%
{digit}             {yylval.str = strdup(yytext); return IntLit;}
{operator}          {yylval.character=yytext[0]; return Operator;}
"Print"             {return Print;}
\(                  {return LParen;}
\)                  {return RParen;}
\,                  {return Comma;}
\;                  {return SemiCln;}
\t                  {}
\r                  {}
\n                  {}

%%
```

parser.y:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


extern int yylex();
extern int yyparse();
extern int yyerror(char *s);
extern char *yytext;

void doPrint(char *s);
char* evaluate(char c, char *s);
char* append(char *s, char *s2);

%}

%union {
  char character;
  char *str;
}

%type <str> Item List
%type <character> Func

%token Print Operator IntLit LParen RParen SemiCln Comma

%%

Prog       : Stmt                                { }
           | Prog Stmt                           { }
           ;
Stmt       : Print LParen List RParen SemiCln    { doPrint($3); }
           ;
List       : List Comma Item                     { $$ = append($1, $3); }
           | Item                                { $$ = $1; }
           ;
Item       : Func LParen List RParen             { $$ = evaluate($1, $3); }
           | IntLit                              { $$ = yylval.str;}
           ;
Func       : Operator                            { $$ = yylval.character; }
           ;

%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    return yyparse();
}

void doPrint(char *s){
    char *stop = strchr(s, ','), *start=s;
    while(stop){
        *stop='\0';
        printf("%s ", start);
        start = stop+1;
        stop = strchr(start, ',');
    }
    printf("%s\n",start);
    free(s);
}

char *evaluate(char c, char *s){
    int res=0;
    if(c == '+'){
        char *stop = strchr(s, ','), *start=s;
        while(stop){
            *stop='\0';
            res += atoi(start);
            start = stop+1;
            stop = strchr(start, ',');
        }
        res += atoi(start);
    } else {
        char *stop = strchr(s, ','), *start=s;
        res = 1;
        while(stop){
            *stop = '\0';
            res *= atoi(start);
            start = stop+1;
            stop = strchr(start, ',');
        }
        res *= atoi(start);
    }
    free(s);
    char *result = (char*)malloc(12); // big enough for a 32 bit integer
    sprintf(result,"%d",res);
    return result;
}

char* append(char *s, char *s2){
    char *result = (char*)realloc(s,strlen(s)+strlen(s2)+2);
    if (result) {
      strcat(result, ",");
      strcat(result, s2);
    }
    else {
        result=(char*)malloc(strlen(s)+strlen(s2)+2);
        sprintf(result,"%s,%s",s,s2);
        free(s);
    }
    free(s2);
    return result;
}

extern int yyerror(char *s)  {
  printf(s);
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: When I input something like `Print(1);` the output is correctly printed as `1`

Comment: I noticed though the action `Stmt  : Print '(' List ')' ';' { doPrint($3); };` isn't even firing after evaluate returns. For example if I add `printf("Print production fired, $3 is: %s\n", $3);` before the `doPrint($3);` the printf part of the action never executes, and so neither does the doPrint. It seems to me yacc is not recognizing the right side of the production.

Comment: `Item : IntLit { $$ = $1;};` In the lex file you dup the string for the number, putting it into the union, then return the IntLit define. In the yacc you should put in for the `Item : IntLit { $$ = yylval.str }` to take the number value

Comment: I might be a little confused at what you're saying. Are you saying `Item : IntLit { $$ = $1;};` should be changed to `Item : IntLit { $$ = yylval.str; };` instead? Doing this changes nothing in the output.

Comment: I got it working. Yes, in the lex you dup the string and you should make that change in the grammar (for IntLit $$=yylval.str). The evaluate() function is defined to return an int, but it returns a char pointer, the function definition and forward definition need to be changed. The evaluate() function has a char *result, which is assigned with sprintf but never has memory allocated. You can't do this, it is a pointer to nothing. Correcting the evaluation signature and pointer usage will fix it for your test cases, and the single Print(1) as well.

Comment: You also should remove the line: `%type <str> IntLit` because it's a terminal token

Comment: In bison, you're allowed to use `%type` with both tokens and non-terminals, but a more portable declaration is `%token <str> IntLit`. Since the token has a value, you should declare it. Deleting the declaration is wrong, and so is the use of `yylval` in a parser action. It will probably work here, but in general `yylval` is usually the value of the *lookahead* token, not the token just shifted. So the change you propose is not correct. (Copying @GeofferyCrawford)

Comment: I am actually using bison 3.7.6-1. It works and is correct. I've done the same thing with yacc 1.9. I made a C compiler and I did this in the same grammar for both, between compiling with yacc or bison I only needed to change the type of yyleng. I didn't pass any value in the token itself,  any value I got from the scanner was the token (an arbitrary define) or what I passed through yylval.